# OEM 11g alerts and notifications arrive together

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, enterprise-manager

I setup the OEM with the Idea to receive Critical messages (emails when the DB, listener, agents and host are down/up) but it doesn't seem to be working.  If I "shutdown abort" the database I wont received any message until I put it up and running, so I receive all the messages together.

Please see image Bellow, that's how I set the alerts, I tested the Email sending and it's working.

- Any Idea what it could be?

[image]

Comment: just trolling but you aren't rebooting the database where the repository is running on right? because... that would sound logical that way

Comment: @Munchi acctually I have everything installed in a local host making some test to move them to Production, are you saying that this won't work because they need to be separate?

Comment: @jcho360 "are you saying that this won't work because they need to be separate" -- Well, how do you think it can send alerts if it's down?

Comment: @Phil I thought that the Email Manager was separate of the database status, just like MsSQL, thanks for clarify this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And that is why Enterprise Manager **Database Control** is inappropriate for this kind of monitoring.
Enterprise Manager **Grid Control/Cloud Control** runs on a seperate host, with a seperate repository database, and that is the tool for this job.